# How to create a Click event in AmChart-StockChart

Tags: javascript, amcharts

Let say there is a Stockchart using AmCharts as below:

https://codepen.io/Volabos/pen/yZwdqg

HTML code part looks as below:

```
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/amcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/serial.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/themes/light.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/amstock.js"></script>
<div id="chartdiv"></div>       

<button type="button">Click Me!</button>
```

At the lower left corner of the page, there is a `Button`. Now I want a functionality that, when user clicks on this Button, the *Zoom=MAX* will be selected (if not selected already.)

Is there any way to achieve that functionality?

Thanks for your pointer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this with `periodSelector.selectPeriodButton()`. Sadly that function is not documented ([docs](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v3/reference/amstockchart/#periodSelector_property)). I forked your code pen and extended it with a function at the end ([updated code pen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PVgYPJ)).

```
document.getElementById('clickme').onclick = event => {
  const period = chart.periodSelector.periods.find(b => b.period === 'MAX');
  // if you know the index:
  // const button = chart.periodSelector.periods[3];
  chart.periodSelector.selectPeriodButton(period);
};
```

**EDIT:**

According to xorspark's answer that's probably not the best method. Maybe you want to use that instead.

Comment: Thanks, this is perfect. Just one question though. Is it possible to have some animation while changing Period? e.g. some sort of FadeIn

Comment: You can add `"panelsSettings": { "startDuration": 1 }` to your chart config, but that only add an initial animation to the chart. An animation during period change is not possible, I think. Maybe it will be possible in amcharts 4.

Comment: Alright. Thanks. I will wait to have such functionality in the next version

Comment: The reason why it isn't documented is because it is an internal method. We highly recommend against using undocumented methods as they are internal methods that can be changed without warning and you get to keep all the pieces when your code breaks. Setting the desired period's `selected` property to true along with calling [`setDefaultPeriod`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptstockchart/PeriodSelector#setDefaultPeriod) is the official way to do this. My answer is below.

Answer (score 2):

The officially supported way to do this is to set the `selected` property of the period in your periodSelector's `periods` array to true (while setting the others to false) and call [`setDefaultPeriod`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptstockchart/PeriodSelector#setDefaultPeriod) afterward to simulate the click.

```
document.getElementById('clickme').onclick = event => {
  chart.periodSelector.periods.forEach((period) => {
    if (period.period === "MAX") {
      period.selected = true;
    }
    else {
      period.selected = false;
    }
  });
  chart.periodSelector.setDefaultPeriod();
};
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/f2dc82bb34648208a062420ed998a5ca?editors=0010)